# SQL query to get most recent date from XML document

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am doing a SQL query against a column with an XML document located.

The XML document looks like the following.

```
<root>
    <date>2016-10-12</date>
    <date>2016-12-01</date>
    <date>2016-11-13</date>
</root>
```

As you can see the dates are out of order.

I am looking for a SQL query that will get the most recent date from the XML document (in this case: 2016-12-01).

Comment: Which DBMS you are using ?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @xml XML

SET @xml = '<root>
    <date>2016-10-12</date>
    <date>2016-12-01</date>
    <date>2016-11-13</date>
     </root>'

SELECT Top 1 x.col.value('.', 'date') AS dates
FROM   @xml.nodes('/root/date') x(col)
ORDER  BY dates DESC
```

Comment: Hi Prdp, you should avoid the `//` (*deep search*) in places, were it is not needed. Just imagine there's an element within a bigger XML with the same name as your root element... Anyway it should be faster to say *Hey! Start at root and navigate along the path!* then ask for any element named *root*...

Answer (score 1):

One way is to read all data and find the maximum externally (external `ORDER BY` with `TOP 1`, like in Prdp's answer, or `MAX()`, eventually with `GROUP BY`).

Another way is a `FLWOR-XQuery`:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<root>
    <date>2016-10-12</date>
    <date>2016-12-01</date>
    <date>2016-11-13</date>
</root>';

SELECT @xml.value('max(for $d in /root/date return xs:date($d))','date')
```

This means:

*Take each value in `/root/date`, return it as `date` and find the highest!*

Both approaches will need to read the whole list, but it should be a bit faster only to look for the maximum value, rather than return a full list and do some external sorting, picking again...

Comment: Good to know.. Really your xml answers are impressive +1